# Call FUNCTION within update statement

Tags: db2

I want to encrypt a field in my table. I have function to do this

```
CREATE FUNCTION baz.encrypt 
(
        p BIGINT
)
RETURNS CHAR(16)
....
```

Now I want to update all rows to be encrypted

```
UPDATE FOO SET BAR =  baz.encrypt(BAR)
```

does not work, either does

```
UPDATE FOO f SET BAR =  SELECT baz.encrypt(BAR) FROM FOO where pk = f.pk
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?  What is the error message you get?  It is a bit surprising that the first UPDATE does not work.  OTOH, the second is definitely not the correct notation and I would indeed expect syntax errors from that.

Comment: the error message `Error: SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "BIGINT".  SQLSTATE=22018
 (State:22018, Native Code: FFFFFE5C)`

Comment: Just solved it.  The problem is the my function expects a BIGINT however my column has alpha chars in it. So the CAST does not work

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it. The problem is the my function expects a BIGINT however my column has alpha chars in it. So the CAST does not work